# Find two maps $f,g:\mathbb F_{q^d}\to \mathbb F_{q^k}$ such that $ker(f)\oplus ker(g)=\mathbb F_{q^l}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

**The base question is:**

Find two maps $f,g:\mathbb F_{q^4}\to \mathbb F_{q^2}$ such that $ker(f)\oplus ker(g)=\mathbb F_{q^4}$

Before the question I am trying to understand the structure and what the map means.

1)**(Structure)** As far as I know, we can consider $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ as a $n$ tuple base abelian group $(\mathbb F_q)^n$ with some ring structure to make it field. I did it for $\mathbb F_{2^2}\cong\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$.

2)**(Map)** We can also consider these fields as a vector space with field $\mathbb F_q$.

With considering these in mind:

Find two $\mathbb F_q$-linear maps $f,g:\mathbb F_{q^4}\to \mathbb F_{q^2}$ such that $ker(f)\oplus ker(g)=\mathbb F_{q^4}$

**My attempt:**  So with these in mind, $\mathbb F_{q^d}$ is a $d$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_q$. If I can find $f,g$(as above) two surjective $\mathbb F_q$- linear map then by dimension theorem from linear algebra their kernel would be $\cong \mathbb F_{q^2}$, two dimensional vector spaces however their intersections must be $\{0\}=ker(f)\cap ker(g)$.

So the answer may be projections?

Let $f:\mathbb F_{q^4}\to \mathbb F_{q^2}\\ (x,y,z,t)\mapsto (x,y)\\ g:\mathbb F_{q^4}\to \mathbb F_{q^2}\\ (x,y,z,t)\mapsto (z,t)$

Easily $ker(f)\cap ker(g)=\{0\}\\ \Rightarrow ker(f)\oplus ker(g)=\mathbb F_{q^4}$

Is that correct for the original statement? Or can you give hint and answer for the original question? I am so confused about these finite fields.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: If "map" means $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear map, then this is just a question of linear algebra. The field $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and the question translates into "find two linear maps $f,g:\mathbb{F}_q^4 \to \mathbb{F}_q^2$ such that $(\ker f) \oplus (\ker g) = \mathbb{F}_q^4$. To solve this, you do not need to know anything about the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{F}_q^d$. Of course, if $f$ and $g$ are instead supposed to be _morphisms of rings_ then the situation becomes quite different.

Comment: if these are morphisms of rings then since they are out of fields they should be injective so that kernel is always trivial.